# SSD not booting on an HP Pavilion HPE-H9 running Windows 7

Tags: boot, ssd

I’m on Windows 7 and my PC is an HP Pavilion HPE-H9 and I just recently got a 500GB Samsung SSD. I used the data migration tool that comes with the CD to copy my data over onto the SSD.

I got into my BIOS and change the settings to make my SSD be the first boot option, and change the storage options to AHCI.

Since my first HDD is RAID I disable it just  to get the SSD to boot.
When I boot I get this error message:

> ERROR: No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.

I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong here and why it’s not booting up or if I’m just doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set both the BIOS and the OS to AHCI. I suggest you go back into the BIOS and set it to IDE. Then try to boot.

To set the OS to AHCI, go to regedit and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services
```

In the left pane, click on `msahci`, in the right pane double click on Start to modify it. In the window that opens change the value from 3 to 0 (zero), and click OK. Then set the BIOS to AHCI.

Btw, AHCI gives you a minor performance advantage but is not vital for proper operation.

Comment: I changed it to IDE and it went through and let it run through the Windows Startup to look for errors, it was attempting repairs and finished.
Afterwards it gets to the "Starting Windows" screen then freezes for a brief second, flashes BSoD for a quick blink of an eye, and restarts.

Comment: Your Samsung program did not work correctly. That is not the first time I have seen that. Use the AOMEI backupper to clone your HDD to the SSD. ==> http://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html Free Macrium also works well but you have to get a version 5.xx  because version 6.xx is for a fee ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I